# Can Virtualization exist in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I will assume many of you guys have heard the question if you can run Docker inside a VM. But I am wondering, can you also do it vice versa?

Background for my question is this, I want to run Docker on multiple bare metal machines and combine them to be one single SSI. Would this be possible? A VM is not an option in my case, since it is meant to be cross platform and Docker already satisfies that.

Correct me if I am wrong, I would like to run Docker on say two bare metal machines and run a single container inside each of them and connect them to become a resource pool that I can access.

Comment: Easy way to find out: Try it. Modern hypervisors can nest instances as deeply as you want though with each layer you take a modest performance hit, typically 5-10%. You won't want to do four or five layers for a production system, but for testing or experimenting you can absolutely do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to take multiple machines and make them look like one computing unit, you could look at putting them all under an orchestration software like Kubernetes, Mesos or Docker Swarm. All of these orchestrators run docker containers.

Comment: I thought about that but my understanding of kubernetes and similar was that you just give it a job and it spins up the same process over a number of slaves. For example, if you give it a mathematical equation it will just spin up a number of predefined processes on said number of slaves n and return the same solution n times or am I wrong?

Comment: At a high level what you say is true. But here are the other things you also get:
    1. Kubernetes will take care of moving the job from one node to another if a particular node crashes (or is taken out of service)
    2. Kubernetes has the concept of services which can front a particular request and load-balance the same across several pods serving that request. Use this concept to break down your computation into several pieces and send each piece as a request to a service which then load-balances this across several pods serving those requests in the back-ground.
    3. Auto-scaling

Comment: That in itself is of course true, but what I would be looking for is parallelization at the machine level. I want to submit job x to a cluster and let it run in parallel without having to optimize the task itself beforehand. If I want to compute 10⁴ places of pi, I would like to just submit it to my cluster and let it run. I looked into MPI but that seems to take additional changing to the task. Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: I think you would have to be responsible for breaking up your task in a way that can be parallelized. Say for instance you want to calculate a function over a set of N values, if you write your function to take a set and calculate over that set, you could parallelize it by breaking original set in M subsets and passing each subset to one container to calculate.

Comment: Yeah I think we are not in the age of true parallelization, did some more reading up and did not find a single article about it. Thanks for your time and answers. Appreciate it.